# Change format preferences for Arduino IDE in Linux

Tags: arduino-ide, linux

How can I change Arduino IDE preferences for formatting? I found the preferences file: `<user>/.arduino15/preferences.txt`, but there are no lines that control IDE formatting. In Windows there is a special file for formatting: `<ArduinoIDE_folder>/lib/formatter.conf`.

Comment: same place `<ArduinoIDE_folder>/lib/formatter.conf`

Comment: @Juraj , as `<ArduinoIDE_folder>` do u mean `<user>/.arduino15`?

Comment: no, `.arduino15` is on Windows `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15`. I installed Arduino IDE on linux into `/home/user/arduino-1.8.5`

Comment: I have my custom formatter.conf in /home/<user>/.arduino15

Answer (score 1):

It happened, that my `formatter.conf` was in `/usr/share/arduino/lib/`. So I copied it to `/home/<user>/.arduino15/` folder and made changes that I needed. And also:

> Copy it in the same folder of file "preferences.txt" and modify the copy. This way, you won't lose your custom formatter settings when upgrading the IDE.

Comment: That is correct.  However, when upgrading, I often the remove the .arduino15 folder as well to make a fresh start. Recently I had to remove the .arduino15 folder without upgrading to a new version. The arduino ide was sometimes slow and had troubles when installing new libraries.